# How to show index not the element

Tags: java

Hi im trying to show the index of the array not the element this is part of my code so far:

```
int randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(15)+1;
double [] distances = new double [randomInt2];

Arrays.sort(distances);// sorts array from highest to lowest        
for (double val : distances) {
System.out.println("["+val+"],");
}

System.out.println("The Nearest to point 1 is point: ");
```

Each index holds an value between 1-1000 but i do not want to show the value i want to show the index so that I can show what indexes are closest to point 1 (which is 0) 
Sorry if im not being clear and if you need me to explain more then I am happy to

Comment: Use `for` loop to have control on the index.

Comment: Use for loop with iteration to show the index...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to show element of array instead of value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048710/how-to-show-element-of-array-instead-of-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to dasblinkenlight's comment I finally understood what you need.

The easiest way to do what you need to do would be to create an object like

```
class Value implements Comparable<Value> {

  int index;
  dobule value;

  public int compareTo(Value val) {
    return Double.compare(this.value, val.value);
  }
}
```

And use it to store the values. Note the `Comparable` implementation - allows you to use `Collections.sort()` and `Arrays.sort()`.

You could also *not use sorting*. Sorting an array is a much more complex operation than finding the minimum value. Just iterate over the array once and find the smallest value and return its index.

```
double minVal = Double.MAX_VALUE;
int minIndex = -1;
for (int i=0, max=distances.length; i<max;i++) {
    if (values[i] < minVal) {
        minVal = values[i];
        minIndex = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("The Nearest to point 1 is point: "+minIndex+" with value "+minVal);
```

**As for indexes**: you can't use standard `foreach` loop if you want to access the index of a given element. One of the reasons is that some collections you may iterate over do not support element ordering (like a `Set`).

You have to use standard `for` loop or track the index yourself.

```
for (int i=0, max=distances.length; i<max;i++) {
    System.out.println("["+i+"] "+distances[i]);
}
```

or

```
int i = 0;
for (double val : distances) {
    System.out.println("["+i+"] "+val);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the help i apprectiate it, sorry i havent really used compare before so not very useful with it however everytime i try to use the code it gets the error "compareTo(Value) in Value cannot implement compareTo(T) in Comparable attempting to assign weaker access priviliges;was public where T is a type-variable; T extends object declared in interface comparable" Any thoughts?

Comment: @user3004630 corrected the code. `public` modifier lacking for method declaration. I guess.

Comment: ah thank you very much was able to get it working :),really appreciate your help was wondering if there is a way of displaying all the values for example nearest to point 1 is point 3(34), then point 2(100)etc..?

Comment: @user3004630 you can and should come to a solution on your own.

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
for (int i=0;i< distances.length;i++) {
      System.out.println("distances["+i+"]");
}
```

Comment: This is quite useless, because it shows `distances[0]`, `distances[1]`, ... OP wants the original index, *before* the sort (see his other question to understand what he's doing). Unfortunately, once he sorts, that index is gone; he needs to change his approach.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to find out the index of the item with lowest distance *in the original array*. When you sort the array, this information is lost, as it will simply indexed from `0..length-1`. Therefore, your answer will always be `0`.

You can do 2 things:
1) Find the minimum value:

```
double[] distances = new double [randomInt2];
// Need copy to for sorting
double[] c = Arrays.copyOf(distances, distances.length);
// Find minimum value
Arrays.sort(c);
double min = c[0];

// Search that value in the original array:
for (int i = 0; i < distances.length; ++i) {
  if (distances[i] == min) {
    System.out.println("Minimum distance at: " + i);
    break;
  }
}
```

2) Store the index information with the distance information:
For this you need to:

1. write your own class, like `public class Distance`, with a distance and index member.
2. Implement a [`Comperator<Distance>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), so that instances are compared by distance
3. Make a function like `Distance[] convertToDistance(double[] array)` that creates a Distance array from your pure double values (if needed)
4. Sort the array using `Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator<? extends T>)` method
5. Get the result from `sortedDistances[0].index`

Answer (score 0):

You can just used an old fashioned `for` loop instead of an enhanced `for` loop:

```
Arrays.sort(distances);// sorts array from highest to lowest        
for (int i = 0; i < distances.lengh; ++i) {
    System.out.println("index: " + i + ":[" + val + "],");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you might every distance let be an object of

```
class Distance {
  public Distance(double dist) {
    this.dist = dist;
    this.id = idcount++;
  }

  static int idcount = 0;
  public int id;
  public double dist;
}
```

and than call the id in every